# VBA XML parsing ''Object variable or With block reference not set'

Tags: xml, vba, parsing

I'm wanting to use VBA in MS Access to read in some XML, but I'm getting a '**Object variable or With block reference not set**' error when parsing this XML...

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
    <GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="B002L7HJAA" status="Success">
        <Product
            xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
            xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
            <Identifiers>
                <MarketplaceASIN>
                    <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
                    <ASIN>B002L7HJAA</ASIN>
                </MarketplaceASIN>
            </Identifiers>
            <CompetitivePricing>
                <CompetitivePrices>
                    <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="false" condition="New" subcondition="New">
                        <CompetitivePriceId>1</CompetitivePriceId>
                        <Price>
                            <LandedPrice>
                                <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                <Amount>14.45</Amount>
                            </LandedPrice>
                        </Price>
                    </CompetitivePrice>
                </CompetitivePrices>
            </CompetitivePricing>
        </Product>
    </GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
</GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse>
```

using this code...

```
Public Function READXML()

Dim objXMLNode1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

Set objXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

objXMLDoc.loadXML ("C:\Users\LW\Desktop\formatted.xml")

XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:ns2='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd' xmlns:ns1='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01'"

objXMLDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

Set objXMLNode1 = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//ns2:Price/ns2:LandedPrice/ns2:Amount")

MsgBox objXMLNode1(0).text

End Function
```

As you can see, I seek to extract the XML value (showing in the XML as **14.45**)

I've spent a good while googling this to no avail, but settled on the above code aftr reading this ['SelectSingleNode' XPath query from XML with multiple Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335954/selectsinglenode-xpath-query-from-xml-with-multiple-namespaces)

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

Comment: What line is giving the error? What is `XmlNamespaces`? It isn't declared. Try using `Option Explicit` and edit your question after you have declared all variables and fixed any typos.

Comment: Hello John, it's the line **MsgBox objXMLNode1(0).text** that is giving the error. Re declaring XMLNameSpace ...good point!

Comment: @peskywinnets you're using the wrong prefix. Try with `//ns1:Price/ns1:LandedPrice/ns1:Amount` instead ...

Comment: Thanks but changing to **//ns1:Price/ns1:LandedPrice/ns1:Amount** still results in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there are several issues to your code:

1. `objXMLDoc` and `XmlNamespaces` are not declared.
2. `LoadXML()` is used for xml strings while `Load()` is for external files.
3. You use a namespace `ns2` in xpath query expression when the tags do not currently have such a prefix.
4. You declare `IXMLDOMNodeList` object but use `selectSingleNode()` method and additionally use a list index for the text value. This raises a type mismatch error.
5. With undeclared namespaces using [MSXML v6.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313372), you must declare the namespace and reference it in xpath expression.

Consider the below adjusted code using `NodeList()`:

```
Public Function READXML()
    Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objXMLNode1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xmlNamespaces As String

    objxmldoc.Load ("C:\Users\LW\Desktop\formatted.xml")
    xmlNamespaces = "xmlns:ns2='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd' " _
                      & "xmlns:ns1='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01'"

    objxmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces
    Set objXMLNode1 = objxmldoc.SelectNodes("//ns1:Price/ns1:LandedPrice/ns1:Amount")

    MsgBox objXMLNode1(0).Text

    Set objxmldoc = Nothing

End Function
```

Alternatively, with the `SelectSingleNode()` method:

```
Public Function READXML()
    Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objXMLNode1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim xmlNamespaces As String

    objxmldoc.Load ("C:\Users\LW\Desktop\formatted.xml")
    xmlNamespaces = "xmlns:ns2='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd' " _
                          & "xmlns:ns1='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01'"

    objxmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces
    Set objXMLNode1 = objxmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns1:Price/ns1:LandedPrice/ns1:Amount")        

    MsgBox objXMLNode1.Text

    Set objxmldoc = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Hello Parfait,I've tried both your code blocks, but I've had to change you Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument .....TO ....... Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60   (because presumably I'm using a later version of Microsoft XML ...V6.0) ...but I still get the same error

Comment: Just to clarify about the error, both your suggestions error at the **Msgbox** line with **''Object variable or With block reference not set'**

Comment: See update. With MSXML  6.0 you must reference the undeclared namespace which you declared as: `ns1`. I add a #5 mentioning this. Similar to what @har07 mentioned.

Comment: Thanks - just tried your edited code (both versions), but still getting the same error at the MsgBox line :-(

Comment: This code works in Excel 2013. Be sure your file path points to correct location.

Comment: I beg your pardon - your edited code now works - thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 1):

The XML elements mentioned in your XPath are in the following default namespace :

```
xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
```

Besides some good suggestions provided in the other answer, you should've used `ns1` prefix, that you have declared to reference the default namespace, in your XPath :

```
XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:ns2='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd' xmlns:ns1='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01'"

objXMLDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

Set objXMLNode1 = objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//ns1:Price/ns1:LandedPrice/ns1:Amount")
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @peskywinnets - this does work per my latest comment but you also have to clean up the code as listed like the mismatched object references.